# PostgreSQL table name (“relation does not exist”), option to ignore case-sensitivity?

Tags: postgresql, websphere, database-migration

I have been trying to migrate an application ear in Websphere Application server that was connected to oracle to PostgreSQL,

I can see a lot of PostgreSQL table name (“relation does not exist”) after the migration, based on what i've read here i see that its because of the way the select scripts were written by the developers. i see that most solutions is to Quote the tablenames as Postgres automatically lowercase the table names during query. however since i am not the person who has the created the ear file, is there any alternative solution that i can apply on the postgress side to ignore case-sensitivity queries?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is by default case insenstive if object names are not quoted:

```
postgres=# \d t;
                 Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 x      | integer |           |          | 

postgres=# select count(*) from t;
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)

postgres=# select count(*) from T;
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

It is only case sensitive if object names are quoted:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from "t";
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)

postgres=# select count(*) from "T";
ERROR:  relation "T" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) from "T";
                             ^
postgres=#
```

AFAIK there is no parameter to change this behaviour.